# Mi codigo no funciona, solo imprime los algunos datos

Tags: java

Soy nueva en Java y mis codigos no han estado funcionando, mi idea es hacer que imprima codigo, modelo, kilometraje y las demas caracteristicas del vehiculo y que tambien imprima el stock al momento de ser vendido un auto, pero no funciona, solo imprime los datos y tampoco me reconoce la variable stock, he estado estudiando mucho con videos y demás, a veces hago exactamente lo mismo del video y aunque a ellos les corre, a mi no y tiene errores, a veces Eclipse me pide llaves extra o ; que no deberian ir, obviamente no los pongo pero aun asi me dice error

`````
public class Vehiculo {
    private int codigo;
    private String marca;
    private String tipo;
    private int modelo;
    private String patente;
    private char kilometraje;
    private int precio;
    private int stock;

    //Constructor por defecto
    public Vehiculo () {
        this.codigo = 123456;
        this.marca = "bmw";
        this.tipo = "auto";
        this.modelo = 2019;
        this.patente = "BKCL78";
        this.kilometraje = 0;
        this.precio = 7500000;
        this.stock = 8;
    }


    //Constructor con atributos
    public Vehiculo (int vCodigo, String vMarca, String vTipo, int vModelo, String vPatente, char vKilometraje, int vPrecio, int vStock) {
        this.codigo = vCodigo;
        this.marca = vMarca;
        this.tipo = vTipo;
        this.modelo = vModelo;
        this.patente = vPatente;
        this.kilometraje = vKilometraje;
        this.precio = vPrecio;
        this.stock = vStock;

    }

    //Setter
    public void setcodigo (int vCodigo) {
        this.codigo = vCodigo;
    }
    //Getter
    public int getcodigo () {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setmarca (String vMarca) {
        this.marca = vMarca;
    }
    public String getmarca () {
        return marca;
    }
    public void settipo (String vTipo) {
        this.tipo = vTipo;
    }
    public String gettipo () {
        return tipo;
    }
    public void setmodelo (int vModelo) {
        this.modelo = vModelo;
    }
    public int getmodelo () {
        return modelo;
    }
    public void setpatente (String vPatente) {
        this.patente = vPatente;
    }
    public String getpatente () {
        return patente;
    }
    public void setkilometraje (char vKilometraje) {
        this.kilometraje = vKilometraje;
    }
    public char getkilometraje () {
        return kilometraje;
    }
    public void setprecio (int vPrecio) {
        this.precio = vPrecio;
    }
    public int getprecio () {
        return precio;
    }
    public void setstock (int vStock) {
        this.stock = vStock;
    } 
    public int getStock () {
        return stock;
    }
    //Metodo vender:
    //Entrada para vender auto
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);

    public int vender() {

        int miVenta = entrada.nextInt();
        if (stock > miVenta) {
        this.stock = (this.stock - miVenta);
        return this.stock;
        }
        System.out.println("Felicidades, su compra ha sido exitosa");
        System.out.println("Nuevo stock = "+this.stock);
    }

    } 
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
//Crear objeto
        Vehiculo v1 = new Vehiculo();
            v1.setcodigo(1234);
            System.out.println("Codigo:"+v1.getcodigo());
            v1.setmarca("bmw");
            System.out.println ("Marca:"+v1.getmarca());
            v1.settipo("auto");
            System.out.println ("Tipo:"+v1.gettipo());
            v1.setmodelo (2019);
            System.out.println ("Modelo:"+v1.getmodelo());
            v1.setpatente ("BKCL78");
            System.out.println ("Patente:"+v1.getpatente());
            v1.setkilometraje ('0');
            System.out.println("Kilometraje:"+v1.getkilometraje());
            v1.setprecio (7500000);
            System.out.println("Precio:"+v1.getprecio());
            v1.setstock (8);
            System.out.println ("Stock:"+v1.getStock());

    }
} ````
`````

Answer (score 2):

En tu clase `Vehiculo`, el método `public int vender() {` debes poner el `return` fuera del `if()`, sino el método no reconocerá el valor de retorno.

```
public int vender() {

    int miVenta = entrada.nextInt();

    if (stock > miVenta) {
        this.stock = (this.stock - miVenta);
    }
    System.out.println("Felicidades, su compra ha sido exitosa");
    System.out.println("Nuevo stock = "+this.stock);

    return this.stock;
}
```

Por lo demás creo que esta todo correcto.

Tu clase `Vehiculo` quedaría así:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vehiculo {
    private int codigo;
    private String marca;
    private String tipo;
    private int modelo;
    private String patente;
    private char kilometraje;
    private int precio;
    private int stock;

    //Constructor por defecto
    public Vehiculo () {
        this.codigo = 123456;
        this.marca = "bmw";
        this.tipo = "auto";
        this.modelo = 2019;
        this.patente = "BKCL78";
        this.kilometraje = 0;
        this.precio = 7500000;
        this.stock = 8;
    }


    //Constructor con atributos
    public Vehiculo (int vCodigo, String vMarca, String vTipo, int vModelo, String vPatente, char vKilometraje, int vPrecio, int vStock) {
        this.codigo = vCodigo;
        this.marca = vMarca;
        this.tipo = vTipo;
        this.modelo = vModelo;
        this.patente = vPatente;
        this.kilometraje = vKilometraje;
        this.precio = vPrecio;
        this.stock = vStock;

    }

    //Setter
    public void setcodigo (int vCodigo) {
        this.codigo = vCodigo;
    }
    //Getter
    public int getcodigo () {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setmarca (String vMarca) {
        this.marca = vMarca;
    }
    public String getmarca () {
        return marca;
    }
    public void settipo (String vTipo) {
        this.tipo = vTipo;
    }
    public String gettipo () {
        return tipo;
    }
    public void setmodelo (int vModelo) {
        this.modelo = vModelo;
    }
    public int getmodelo () {
        return modelo;
    }
    public void setpatente (String vPatente) {
        this.patente = vPatente;
    }
    public String getpatente () {
        return patente;
    }
    public void setkilometraje (char vKilometraje) {
        this.kilometraje = vKilometraje;
    }
    public char getkilometraje () {
        return kilometraje;
    }
    public void setprecio (int vPrecio) {
        this.precio = vPrecio;
    }
    public int getprecio () {
        return precio;
    }
    public void setstock (int vStock) {
        this.stock = vStock;
    } 
    public int getStock () {
        return stock;
    }
    //Metodo vender:
    //Entrada para vender auto
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);

    public int vender() {

        int miVenta = entrada.nextInt();

        if (stock > miVenta) {
            this.stock = (this.stock - miVenta);
        }
        System.out.println("Felicidades, su compra ha sido exitosa");
        System.out.println("Nuevo stock = "+this.stock);
        return this.stock;
    }
}
```

Y tu clase `Main` así:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Crear objeto
        Vehiculo v1 = new Vehiculo();
        v1.setcodigo(1234);
        System.out.println("Codigo:"+v1.getcodigo());
        v1.setmarca("bmw");
        System.out.println ("Marca:"+v1.getmarca());
        v1.settipo("auto");
        System.out.println ("Tipo:"+v1.gettipo());
        v1.setmodelo (2019);
        System.out.println ("Modelo:"+v1.getmodelo());
        v1.setpatente ("BKCL78");
        System.out.println ("Patente:"+v1.getpatente());
        v1.setkilometraje ('0');
        System.out.println("Kilometraje:"+v1.getkilometraje());
        v1.setprecio (7500000);
        System.out.println("Precio:"+v1.getprecio());
        v1.setstock (8);
        System.out.println ("Stock:"+v1.getStock());
    }
}
```

Lo he probado en el IDE eclipse y me funciona.

**Output**

```
Codigo:123456
Marca:bmw
Tipo:auto
Modelo:2019
Patente:BKCL78
Kilometraje:
```

Espero que te sirva mi respuesta!